# Searching in database ajax or $_POST PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I just need some advices here. I have a search form at the top of my page. And then I have a table which displaying all of my database.

The form will permit to the user to display what he exactly want in the base (with specific date, etc).

I could do that simply with php and sql query. The problem is that I would like to make it pleasant for the user. I would like to keep the informations in the inputs of the search after it is done, in order to just change one or 2 fields if it is needed to search again.

So the question is, should I use AJAX method with javascript and in this case, how to get a table with all the wanted values, or do you think that a POST method on the form with action=the same page with using the POST_VALUES to fill the inputs would be better?

Answer (score 0):

Well, its up to you whether you want to use Ajax or Javascript. Ajax based forms are usually used when the user needs to stay on same page after submitting the form and without refreshing the page.

If you use ajax then you might want to display a progress loading image so the user knows your form is being submitted and that he should not try to submit it twice by mistake.

There are also security related issues that can be considered, for example should the form be protected again automatic use, for example bots or script hackers?. If so then the form can use captcha.

Another security consideration is sanitizing the input data before it is saved to database. This should prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Another security consideration is prevention against Cross Site Scripting attacks. For example it should not be possible to use the form within other websites or iframes.

You should also consider usability and accessibility issues such as mobile devices and users with visual impairments.

You can fetch the data from database using a php extension such as mysqli, if you are using a MySQL database

Comment: The distinction between AJAX here and JavaScript seems confused. AJAX is just a method of JavaScript-based form submission. "Sanitizing" isn't the correct term. "Escaping" is. The difference might seem academic but it's important. The same goes for XSS issues. CSRF is a whole other can of worms.